# Scaling pgfplots matching papersize

Tags: pgfplots, scaling

I'm facing some problems at the moment with scaling some diagrams so that they each fit on a page (landscape) in my appendix.

Does anyone has some suggestions how to solve this? Any help would be really appreciated.

One of the diagramms looks like this. I also included the "main settings" as I am not sure, if they are important (papersize, header etc.)

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % Improves appearance of some cm-super fonts
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}    % warns about some obsolete latex constructs
\documentclass[
   12pt,                % font size 12pt
   a4paper,             % layout for DIN A4
   oneside,             % layout for one sided printing
   headinclude,         % include head in layout computation
   headsepline,         % horizontal line below head
   BCOR12mm,            % correction for fixation
   DIV16,               % DIV-value for creating the print space, (see scrguien.pdf)
   parskip=half,         % spacing between paragraphs
   openany,             % chapters may start on even and odd pages
   bibliography=totoc,            % put bibliography into table of contents
   numbers=noenddot,    % chapter numbers without full stop
   headlines=2.1,       %test overfull
   captions=tablehe
ading,   % use table headings with correct spacing
   fleqn                % float equations to left margin
          % 1,5er Zeilenabstand
]{scrbook}[2007/12/24]  % scrbook-Version min. v2.98 from 2007/12/24

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % change to your encoding (e.g. utf8)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % correct pdf output (correct umlaut charaters)
\usepackage{lmodern}             % fonts for pdf-file creation (use Type1 instead of Type3) - only needed, if cmsuper is not installed
%                                 % check the resulting pdf-file: fonts should been embedded, subsetted and of type 1 (NOT type 3!)
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}  % place the subscripts and superscripts in the right position
\usepackage{amsfonts}            % additional fonts like \mathbb, \mathfrak
\usepackage{amssymb}             % additional symbols
\usepackage{url}                 % support for urls
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\newcommand{\grad}{\ensuremath{^\circ}} %Grad
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}


%\usepackage{ngerman}             % new german orthography
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrpage2}            % head and foot layout
\usepackage{ushort}              % complex values require an underline (use \ushort or \ushortw)
\usepackage{units}               % package for setting units in a typographically correct way (e.g. \unit[3]{cm})
\usepackage{booktabs}            % package provides additional commands to enhance the quality of tables
\usepackage{datetime}            % provides \pdfdate command

\usepackage[german]{fancyref}

\usepackage{setspace}            % Anderthalbzeiliger Zeilenabstand
%\onehalfspacing
%\setstretch{1,6}
\addtolength{\headheight}{3pt} %test Warning using a very small headheight
\linespread{1.3}

\numberwithin{equation}{section} % amsmath: numbering equations

\pagestyle{scrheadings}          % enable scrheadings layout for head and foot

%Fußnoten nicht eingerückt
\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0pt}

\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
 % non pdflatex settings (normal latex compiler assumed)
 \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\else
 % different settings for the pdflatex compiler
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \usepackage{epstopdf}           % enables automatic conversion from .eps to .pdf graphic files; run MikTeX as "latex --enable-write18"
 \usepackage[pdftex,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
 \pdfcompresslevel=9
 \pdfinfo{
    /CreationDate (D:20050518110000) % date format is year(4) month(2) day(2) hour(2) minute(2) second(2)
    /ModDate      (D:\pdfdate)
 }

\fi








\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8,
            grid style={dashed}}

\begin{filecontents}{Data_Geburt_Tod.csv}
Jahr    Geburten    Sterbefaelle
1602    11  1
1603    20  6
1604    19  6
1605    23  11
1606    18  7
1607    20  6
1608    27  8
1609    21  3
1610    15  84
1611    {}  {}
1612    24  4
1613    28  9
1614    28  3
1615    13  {}
1616    22  5
1617    21  {}
1618    24  5
1619    24  4
1620    5   2
1621    13  3
1622    14  8
1623    15  2
1624    17  1
1625    14  2
1626    14  3
1627    6   1
1628    16  1
1629    15  1
1630    8   5
1631    15  6
1632    7   2
1633    12  13
1634    11  17
1635    1   79
1636    10  38
1637    13  11
1638    1   21
1639    8   4
1640    7   1
1641    5   5
1642    11  1
1643    6   1
1644    17  3
1645    22  2
1646    24  5
1647    22  2
1648    29  5
1649    13  4
1650    27  7
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
            width=1.9\textwidth,height=0.9\textheight,
            xmin=1602,
            title={Bevölkerungsentwicklung zwischen 1600 und 1650},
            xtick={1600,1605,1610,1615,1620,1625,1630,1635,1640,1645,1650},
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
            xlabel={Jahr},
            y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
            extra y ticks={84, 79},
            extra y tick labels={{84},{79}},
            extra y tick style={grid=major,
                tick label style={xshift=-1cm}},
            ylabel={Personen},
            enlarge x limits=0.01,
            bar width=5pt]
  \pgfplotstableread{Data_Geburt_Tod.csv}\loadedtable;

    \addplot table[x=Jahr, y=Geburten] {\loadedtable};
    \addplot table[x=Jahr, y=Sterbefaelle] {\loadedtable};   
    \legend{Geburten, Sterbefaelle} 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the `width` and `height` as

```
        width=1.35\textwidth,
        height=0.9\textheight,
```

as you did already, but provided incorrect dimensions. On the other hand if this is needed for all plots put it in the `\pgfplotsset`.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % Improves appearance of some cm-super fonts
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}    % warns about some obsolete latex constructs
\documentclass[
   12pt,                % font size 12pt
   a4paper,             % layout for DIN A4
   oneside,             % layout for one sided printing
   headinclude,         % include head in layout computation
   headsepline,         % horizontal line below head
   BCOR12mm,            % correction for fixation
   DIV16,               % DIV-value for creating the print space, (see scrguien.pdf)
   parskip=half,         % spacing between paragraphs
   openany,             % chapters may start on even and odd pages
   bibliography=totoc,            % put bibliography into table of contents
   numbers=noenddot,    % chapter numbers without full stop
   headlines=2.1,       %test overfull
   captions=tablehe
ading,   % use table headings with correct spacing
   fleqn                % float equations to left margin
          % 1,5er Zeilenabstand
]{scrbook}[2007/12/24]  % scrbook-Version min. v2.98 from 2007/12/24

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % change to your encoding (e.g. utf8)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % correct pdf output (correct umlaut charaters)
\usepackage{lmodern}             % fonts for pdf-file creation (use Type1 instead of Type3) - only needed, if cmsuper is not installed
%                                 % check the resulting pdf-file: fonts should been embedded, subsetted and of type 1 (NOT type 3!)
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}  % place the subscripts and superscripts in the right position
\usepackage{amsfonts}            % additional fonts like \mathbb, \mathfrak
\usepackage{amssymb}             % additional symbols
\usepackage{url}                 % support for urls
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\newcommand{\grad}{\ensuremath{^\circ}} %Grad
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}


%\usepackage{ngerman}             % new german orthography
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrpage2}            % head and foot layout
\usepackage{ushort}              % complex values require an underline (use \ushort or \ushortw)
\usepackage{units}               % package for setting units in a typographically correct way (e.g. \unit[3]{cm})
\usepackage{booktabs}            % package provides additional commands to enhance the quality of tables
\usepackage{datetime}            % provides \pdfdate command

\usepackage[german]{fancyref}

\usepackage{setspace}            % Anderthalbzeiliger Zeilenabstand
%\onehalfspacing
%\setstretch{1,6}
\addtolength{\headheight}{3pt} %test Warning using a very small headheight
\linespread{1.3}

\numberwithin{equation}{section} % amsmath: numbering equations

\pagestyle{scrheadings}          % enable scrheadings layout for head and foot

%Fußnoten nicht eingerückt
\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0pt}

\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
 % non pdflatex settings (normal latex compiler assumed)
 \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\else
 % different settings for the pdflatex compiler
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \usepackage{epstopdf}           % enables automatic conversion from .eps to .pdf graphic files; run MikTeX as "latex --enable-write18"
 \usepackage[pdftex,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
 \pdfcompresslevel=9
 \pdfinfo{
    /CreationDate (D:20050518110000) % date format is year(4) month(2) day(2) hour(2) minute(2) second(2)
    /ModDate      (D:\pdfdate)
 }

\fi








\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8,
            grid style={dashed},
            }

\begin{filecontents}{Data_Geburt_Tod.csv}
Jahr    Geburten    Sterbefaelle
1602    11  1
1603    20  6
1604    19  6
1605    23  11
1606    18  7
1607    20  6
1608    27  8
1609    21  3
1610    15  84
1611    {}  {}
1612    24  4
1613    28  9
1614    28  3
1615    13  {}
1616    22  5
1617    21  {}
1618    24  5
1619    24  4
1620    5   2
1621    13  3
1622    14  8
1623    15  2
1624    17  1
1625    14  2
1626    14  3
1627    6   1
1628    16  1
1629    15  1
1630    8   5
1631    15  6
1632    7   2
1633    12  13
1634    11  17
1635    1   79
1636    10  38
1637    13  11
1638    1   21
1639    8   4
1640    7   1
1641    5   5
1642    11  1
1643    6   1
1644    17  3
1645    22  2
1646    24  5
1647    22  2
1648    29  5
1649    13  4
1650    27  7
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
            width=1.35\textwidth,
            height=0.9\textheight,
            %width=1.9\textwidth,height=0.9\textheight,
            xmin=1602,
            title={Bevölkerungsentwicklung zwischen 1600 und 1650},
            xtick={1600,1605,1610,1615,1620,1625,1630,1635,1640,1645,1650},
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
            xlabel={Jahr},
            y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
            extra y ticks={84, 79},
            extra y tick labels={{84},{79}},
            extra y tick style={grid=major,
                tick label style={xshift=-1cm}},
            ylabel={Personen},
            enlarge x limits=0.01,
            bar width=5pt]
  \pgfplotstableread{Data_Geburt_Tod.csv}\loadedtable;

    \addplot table[x=Jahr, y=Geburten] {\loadedtable};
    \addplot table[x=Jahr, y=Sterbefaelle] {\loadedtable};
    \legend{Geburten, Sterbefaelle}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option will be to use `tikzscale package. But here you have to put your plot as a separate file. i.e., save

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
.
.
.
your plot.
.
.
\end{tikzpicture}
```

as a file `plot.tikz`and use

```
\usepackage{tikzscale}
```

and

```
\includegraphics[width=<dimen>]{plot.tikz}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - that worked pretty well. I just noticed that this solution works only in a `doment-enviroment`. I just tried to put it in a `begin{figure} end[figure} environment and notices that it wont rotate anymore. Is there possibly a fix for that? I would not really like to abandon captions.

Comment: Okay, I found out. \rotatebox{90}{} was my friend ;-)